# iterate over multiple list and use it as a value growing dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have 2 lists of the same size:

```
list1 = ['event1','event2']   #up to event-n
list2 = ['desc1', 'desc2']    #up to desc-n
```

I want to iterate over 2 lists and put their data as a **value** in to a dictionary in a dynamic way.

**Expected output:**

```
payload={
  "outer_key" : [ {
    "key1" : event1,
    "key2" : desc1 
  },
  {
    "key1" : event2,
    "key2" : desc2 
  }
 ]}
```

Since there are "n" number of **events** and **desc** , is there a way to make a flexible dictionary, which will grow according to list size?

Note:  each dictionary inside a list is of fixed size.
i.e. each dictionary have only 2 keys- key1 and key2.

My attempt :

```
import itertools
list1 = ['event1','event2']   #up to event-n
list2 = ['desc1', 'desc2']    #up to desc-n
for f, b in itertools.izip(list1, list2):
     payload={
     "outer_key" : [ {
     "key1" : f,
     "key2" : b
     }]}
print payload
```

Obvious and **actual output**:

```
payload= {'outer_key': [{'key1': 'event2', 'key2':'desc2'}]}
```

What is the best way to dynamically grow **key1** and **key2** as per the list size ?

Edit 1: Assume that there is only 1 "outer_key" and it has only 1 value- which is a list. And list has "n" number of dictionaries.

Comment: What's "outer_key" ?

Comment: outer_key is a fixed key and it's value is list of dictionary.

Comment: Added the information in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the list with each iteration of the loop. Instead instantiate the list outside the loop and append to it inside.

```
import itertools
list1 = ['event1','event2']   #up to event-n
list2 = ['desc1', 'desc2']    #up to desc-n
payload = {
   "outer_key" : []
}
for f, b in itertools.izip(list1, list2):
     payload["outer_key"].append({"key1" : f, "key2" : b})
print payload
```